# How to run a exe file as a window service?

Tags: go

I want to run a `exe` file as a window service.

Is there any `golang` open source or any `golang` `api` to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the Documentation Here: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc

```
import "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc"
```

and then use

```
func Run(name string, handler Handler) error
```

to start it.

There's a whole lot of other functions that will be useful to you on the page I linked, so you should definitely look at that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use exec Package that runs external commands,
for example:

```
import "os/exec"

cmd := exec.Command("your_exe_file")
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

for more info https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/

Comment: The op did not ask to run a command from the app, but to run the app itself as a Windows Service.